# How to remove the Facebook Developer app itself?

Tags: html, facebook

I want to remove the developer app from my Facebook account and return to a simple profile. I think its like developer profile currently. and when I click on setting button on the top right corner of the page there are "create and app" and "Manage apps" links which is not available for simple normal accounts.

I also can not rearrange and add my groups to favorites which I think is because of the developer app.

Is there anyone who knows how to remove the developer app?

I searched a lot and there is no remove application option anywhere on developer.facebook.com !!!
please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Go to

> https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

Select the app you want to delete, then click `edit app` then

click on `delete app` (last option on left pane)

you are done.

Comment: I don't know if this worked by the time it was posted, but now it's not working this way and I couldn't find an easy way to remove the developers app from my account. Do you know how to do it?